# Javascript, adding an removing CSS on button press (shutter reloaded)

Tags: javascript, lightbox, shutter

I've tried editing the Shutter Reloaded script to simply add in a bit of CSS when the resize button is pressed, but I can't get it to work as my javascript knowledge is terrible. This is what I've tied doing:

```
  Resize : function(ln) {
             if ( this.resizing ) return;
             if ( ! this.I('shShutter') ) return;
             var W = this.I('shWrap');
             if ( W ) W.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.setTimeout(function(){shutterReloaded.resizing = null},500);
    window.setTimeout(new Function('shutterReloaded.VP = null;shutterReloaded.Make("'+ln+'");'),100);
    this.resizing = true;
    document.getElementById("colour").style.property=display="none";
    },
```

I'm wanting to add: `display: "none";` to the `div #colour,` but yeah can't seem to get it to work.

The page its on is this: [Link](http://www.portablespacemuseum.com/green/)

It probably helps to have the rest of the code too:

[shutter.js](http://www.portablespacemuseum.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/shutter_reloaded/shutter.js)

Any idea's guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, try this:

```
document.getElementById("colour").style.display="none";
```

Comment: Ah you're awesome, thanks! It's done what I've needed it to, thanks for taking the time to answer!